# Running H2 database multiple instances in Spring Boot Services

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, h2, multiple-instances

I have created a Spring Boot app using embedded in memory H2 database. The application is running properly. H2 database we console is reachable on browser `http://localhost:8080/h2` and application services are reachable at `localhost:8080/context/service-endpoint`. It means both H2 database and application is also accessible on same port.

Now, I run second instance of Spring boot application by passing `--server.port=8888`, Spring Boot application starts on port 8888 but there is failure in H2DB up and running.

Here, I presume that if in the first instance running on port 8080 then in second instance of same application with different port should also start H2 DB on specified different port that is in this case : 8888. However, it is failing.

Please help.

LOG:

```
15:08:02.019 [main] INFO com.rest.jpa.SpringJpaRestServicesApplication - Application starting....

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

2019-06-25 15:08:03.179  INFO 16376 --- [           main] c.r.j.SpringJpaRestServicesApplication   : Starting SpringJpaRestServicesApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on LP-5CD6242Q0M with PID 16376 (C:\project\spring-jpa-rest-services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by kumar.shorav in C:\project)
2019-06-25 15:08:03.182  INFO 16376 --- [           main] c.r.j.SpringJpaRestServicesApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-06-25 15:08:05.149  INFO 16376 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-06-25 15:08:05.288  INFO 16376 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 120ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-06-25 15:08:06.162  INFO 16376 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$582af4bf] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-06-25 15:08:07.355  INFO 16376 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
2019-06-25 15:08:07.440  INFO 16376 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-06-25 15:08:07.441  INFO 16376 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]
2019-06-25 15:08:07.722  INFO 16376 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-06-25 15:08:07.723  INFO 16376 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4437 ms
2019-06-25 15:08:08.131  INFO 16376 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-06-25 15:08:09.400 ERROR 16376 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database may be already in use: null. Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:617) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.convertIllegalStateException(MVTableEngine.java:193) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:173) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine.init(MVTableEngine.java:95) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2739) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:769) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:319) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:313) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:178) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:161) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:31) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:336) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:169) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:148) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157) [spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) [spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) [spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:73) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:142) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:113) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7701b72e.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$6(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7701b72e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$81fef358.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) [spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) [spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7701b72e.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.rest.jpa.SpringJpaRestServicesApplication.main(SpringJpaRestServicesApplication.java:20) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[spring-jpa-rest-services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[spring-jpa-rest-services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[spring-jpa-rest-services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[spring-jpa-rest-services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file is locked: nio:C:/Users/kumar.shorav/test.mv.db [1.4.199/7]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:883) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.open(FileStore.java:172) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(MVStore.java:390) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:3343) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:162) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar!/:na]
    ... 95 common frames omitted

2019-06-25 15:08:09.404  WARN 16376 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database may be already in use: null. Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-199]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:328) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:73) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:142) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:113) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7701b72e.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$6(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7701b72e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$81fef358.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) [spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) [spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7701b72e.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolve
```

Comment: What is , Why multiple instance of H2 database?

Comment: @DoNhuVyhow do I would be able to run the application multiple instances.

Comment: Do you use in memory mode of H2?

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski Yes, I am using in memory embedded H2.

Comment: @Kumar could you also add the error massage into question for sure.

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski OK..I am adding it.

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an H2 expert, but the exception here explains well what happens.

From your stacktrace:

```
The file is locked: nio:C:/Users/kumar.shorav/test.mv.db
```

So I believe the first instance stores its h2 stuff in this file, it gets locked by this process.
Now the second instance comes up and it probably has the same set of configurations and among them where to store the file (in the same place).

So when it starts, the file is already locked, and H2 of the second instance can't start.

Now this doesn't correlate with the fact that you say that H2 runs purely in memory, at least its not what the exception says

Comment: Also check the connection string is it looks like 'jdbc:h2:mem:db1'?

Comment: @Mark Yes, I passed different file name as indicated above by you. It is working now. Thanks

Comment: You can also use multiple application.yml files and in each one you can specify a name of your H2 db like : `application-dev.yml` , `application-prod.yml` etc. Then you run your spring boot app with command `--spring.profiles.active=dev` or `prod`

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after stopping the h2.bat job.